# Fancybox | Ajax request not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

I've been trying for hours to make fancybox to load a php file, with no success...

Here's the details:

You can visit the website having the problem [here](http://patrascity.gr/events-pc/pc-festival/1610-diethnes-festival-patras-2012.html). Fancybox request is called when you click either "Παλαιά Δημοτικά Λουτρά" or "Αρχαίο Ωδείο", next to each image.

First, page's content is loaded through an ajax request. This page contains the link:

```
<a class="area_fancybox" href="http://www.mysite/fancy_areas.php?areasName=' . $the_area . '">' . $the_area . '</a>
```

Where $the_area variable is the parameter I want to pass to the php file that fancybox will load. Now when page's content has loaded, I add the fancybox code, like this.

```
jQuery('#diethnes_festival_2012').load('../../../diethnes_festival_2012.php', function() {
  jQuery("a.area_fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

When you click "area_fancybox" link, fancybox starts loading, but nothing happens...

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Fancybox` ajax call requests from url starting with `www` while your link doesn't have this part. If you load your page with `www.` at the begining then the call works.
This is due to the `allow-control-access-policy` of the browsers. Always use `firebug` or `chrome developer tools` to look for errors in console.

Comment: Thank you very much Wojtek. You were really quick and helpful! Instead of hardcoding the domain, I added $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], so it will work both with "www" and without.

Comment: Could you please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351626/jquery-fancybox-with-ajax/31352383)  question? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's a cross-domain issue (you're not allowed to load content from *www.mysite* from the domain *mysite*.  You'll notice that if you visit the site with *www* in the URL, then it works as-is:  http://www.mysite/events-pc/pc-festival/1610-diethnes-festival-patras-2012.html

I recommend using a relative path in the *href*, which should make your code work for both cases:

```
<a class="area_fancybox" href="/fancy_areas.php?areasName=Παλαιά Δημοτικά Λουτρά">Παλαιά Δημοτικά Λουτρά</a>
```

Btw, I recommend checking out Firebug if you haven't already-- it's really helpful for debugging this kind of thing.  If you're using Chrome, just hit ctrl-shift-J.

Comment: Relative path won't work though...
Cause it will search for: mysite/events-pc/pc-festival/1610-diethnes-festival-patras-2012.html/fancy_areas.php?areasName=Παλαιά Δημοτικά Λουτρά