# Fancybox won't load ajax call, instead just links to content

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

This is my html (or part of it):

```
<span class="cell-option">
    <a href="/1/edit">
        Edit
    </a>
</span>
<span class="cell-option">
    <a href="/1/edit" class="quick-type-link convert-absolute">
        Edit2
    </a>
</span>
```

And this is my Javascript:

```
$('a.quick-type-link').fancybox();
$('a.image-box-link').fancybox();
```

The call to a.image-box-link works (It makes the images Fancyboxs, though I didn't show the code for the images, it is the exact same as the .quick-type-link). I'm working with localhost (`127.0.0.1`), just so you know.

The answer to this question: [Fancybox | Ajax request not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971670/fancybox-ajax-request-not-working) made me try changing the links to be absolute, but that didn't work and would have been a pain to maintain anyway because I don't know what URL it will be hosted on.

FANCYBOX: http://fancybox.net/

Comment: What is supposed to happen when you click the Edit2 link? Where is the ajax call?

Comment: @Pjack Sorry. I should have linked to the FancyBox API. Fancybox is a model dialoge box that can load content using ajax.

Comment: try testing in a server environment for ajax and iframes modes .... you are using fancybox v1.3.4, aren't you?

Comment: @JFK Actually, I'm using 2.1.5

Comment: 2.1.5 does make a difference.

Comment: /1/edit, is that supposed to perform a custom ajax call?

Comment: Yes it does make a difference since http://fancybox.net/ is the link to v1.3.4

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the version I was using. Though the website didn't say, it turns out I need `fancybox.ajax` as a class for any items I want to have an ajax call.

Comment: exactly, I was going to tell you that :) that's why I asked if you are performing a **custom** ajax call.

Comment: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples (various types) shows you explicitly what html and js you should be using (this is why I asked about the version)